# Forward engineering data model from visio 2010

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling, visio

I have heard here that this is possible in "Visio Enterprise Architect" .. is this correct? if yes, what type of visio is this? A standalone app like visio 2010?

Any other plugin that can help in achieving this from Visio 2010? If not, what are other softwares that can do that i.e Data Model to SQL Server DB.

Comment: @catcall .. I have no idea how o accept an answer here, I can't see any link. can u pls guide me ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last Visio Enterprise Architect was 2003/2005. Visio 2010 does not support forward engineering out of box and this was a stupid idea from Microsoft.

But there is a simple plugin for Visio 2010 which generates SQL from your DB scheme:  http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com